# Pagination Links Don't Render

Tags: pagination

I am using {pagination_links} and the code is not rendering.

Here is my complete code for my channel entries:

```
<section class="blog">

{exp:channel:entries channel="journal" disable="categories|category-fields|member-data" limit="1"}
<article class="blog-summary m-all t-all d1-d4 ">
<time>{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%t"}</time>
<h3>{title}</h3>

<div class="m-all t1-t2 d1-d2">
{journal_text_1}
</div>

<div class="m-all t1-t2 d3-d4">
{journal_text_2}
</div>

{exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}"}
<figure class="blog-image m-all t1-t2 d-all"><img src="{image:url:large}"  alt="{image:description}"></figure>
{/exp:channel_images:images}

<hr class="m-all t1-t2 d-all m-clear t-clear d-clear">
</article>

<div class="m-all t1-t2 d-all m-clear t-clear d-clear">
{pagination_links}
    {page}
        <a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
    {/page}
{/pagination_links}
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}

</section>
```

And on the front end it renders like this:

{pagination_links} {page} {pagination_page_number} {/page} {/pagination_links}

Am I missing something?

NT

Comment: What version of EE are you using? EE 2.4.0 introduced some changes to pagination so the syntax may be different.

Comment: Sorry, that's 2.3.0, not 2.4.0.

Comment: Currently using 2.5.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap the `{pagination_links}` tags with `{paginate}` tags:

```
{paginate}
    {pagination_links}
        {page}
            <a href="{pagination_url}">{pagination_page_number}</a>
        {/page}
    {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}
```

See [this comment](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html#9448) in the docs (which do a crap-tacular job of documenting pagination, btw).

Answer (score 1):

The code looks correct to me. I don't think it's a required paramater but try adding `paginate='bottom'` to your channel entries open tag. That would make it:

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="journal" disable="categories|category-fields|member-data" limit="1" paginate="bottom"}
```

Comment: Tried that originally but no luck :(

Comment: What version of EE?